# What is the minimum work to get Angular working in a ASP.NET MVC/WEB Api template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am transitioning over to using Angular and Web API together. The MVC/Web API templates in visual studio have the root path point to the HomeController.cs which returns a View..

How do I get that root path to point to a angular html file? Does the concept of server side routing need to go away somehow ? I am confused and have not found any info on how you transition from that MVC/Web API template to using angular and what do you do with the extra files that the template creates.. As far as I understand it is

1. Create Web API template in VS
2. Create index.html page in the root directory that contains the ng directive to the other angular html pages and serves as a sort of master page for them
3. Then I guess I need to get rid of ASP.NET MVC routing so that it works in the old school webforms type of way of specifying a file to be the default file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me take a stab at it as we are using the same stack of ASP.Net MVC, WebApi and AngularJS. Also assuming you are creating a SPA.

First and foremost, keep Web API out of picture. It's applicability is only limited to sending data in different formats, there is no view concepts in it.

You can use both server side routing and angular routing to serve views to the user. They can in fact complement each other.

Like master page, angular would need to have a main page, which has `ng-app` declaration. From a MVC standpoint `home\index.cshtml` can be loaded for the initial view. The server size view generated for this `index` page can contain the `ng-app` directive and `ng-view` directive.

`ng-view` is the main area where views would get swapped\loaded.You can can compare `ng-view` as equivalent to `@RenderBody()` method on the server side. **<strike>Remember to remove `@RenderBody()` call from master page when using Angular</strike>**. You don't remove RenderBody as it loads the main page. Instead an index page should be loaded with just a div with `ng-view` in it.

You would now create server side views for each partial view loaded in `ng-view`. For example, there could be a `userlist.cshtml` view that gets loaded when route on client changes to `#/users` on the client. To load these view from server you need to provide `templateUrl` in the `$routeProvide`, this template url would be resolved by server routing ( `/user/index`).

Things to keep in mind while creating these child views is

- They should not inherit any master page.
- Hence should only send content that needs to be injected into the `ng-view` section, so no `<html>, <body>` tags.
- They can contain angular binding and other angular declarative stuff.

Once the initial template is loaded by Angular, it may make a call to server again to load data for the template. This is where the Web API comes into picture. A call like `/api/users` would return json data about all user. The data returned then can be used to bind the view + data together.

Hope i have made myself clear.

Comment: I found the Breeze/Angular template for vs2012 so I am going to try to use that as a starting point have you looked at that?

Comment: I found the Breeze/Angular template for vs2012 so I am going to try to use that as a starting point have you looked at that? are there multiple client views for a single server view?  I is the point of the server view for when you maybe want a completely new section with a new set of client partial views? It is somewhat clear but I wish there was a simple template like the one you describe to get me started..